# How to remove all VM products without losing VM configuration

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart

Well... that's my question. How can I remove my VM products without losing my VM configuration.

Comment: Can you not simply select all products in the list and click the *delete* button?

Comment: There're +4500, and there's no "show all" button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One to do this, is to open PhpMyAdmin and go to the `#__virtuemart_products` table.

Here, you check all products and delete them.

Or you can open the SQL tab and type in the following query:

```
TRUNCATE xxxx_virtuemart_products
```

Where `xxxx` is your database table prefix.

Comment: Not sure what version you're on, but don't forget to consider related tables that have a product id